# Object with highest count in a Groovy list

Tags: arraylist, groovy, closures

I have a list of Parcel objects, am trying to write a closure that picks the parcel object with highest count

```
class Parcel { 
    int id
    int count
    String sender
    String recipient 
    Parcel(int _id, int _count) {
        id = _id
        count = _count 
    } 
}

def parcels = [new Parcel(1,5), new Parcel(2,1), new Parcel(3,3), new Parcel(4,2), new Parcel(5,4) ]
```

I tried below code which works fine

```
parcels.sort{it.count}
parcels.reverse().first()
```

Am wondering is there a better way to pick the parcel with highest count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that this option should work:

```
assert parcels.max { it.count }.count == 5
```